# Android 's requestPermissions on landscape but the dialog shown in portrait before rotate to landscape

Tags: android, permissions

My app starts on landscape as intended and I want to ask for permission with requestPermissions().

However, the permission dialog first shown in portrait then its rotate itself to landscape which behavior I don't like. I want the permission dialog start in landscape from the start.

I tried adding requestPermissions() in onViewCreated and onResume but still the same behavior.

I move the permission related codes to PermissionsFragment and using callback when successfully acquired all permissions.

Even when doing this all without that PermissionsFragment and done in MainActivity will result in the same behaviour as well. I even tried adding the permission codes in onPostResume to no avail.

Is there anyway to force the permission dialog to show in landscape mode straight away?

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PermissionsFragment firstFragment = new PermissionsFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment instanceof PermissionsFragment) {
            ((PermissionsFragment) fragment).setOnPermissionsAcquiredListener(() -> {
                MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment, "MainFragment").commit();
            });
        }
    }

}
```

**PermissionsFragment:**

```
public class PermissionsFragment extends Fragment {
    private PermissionsAcquiredListener callback;

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 10;
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED = {
            permission.CAMERA,
            permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            permission.INTERNET,
    };

    public void setOnPermissionsAcquiredListener(PermissionsAcquiredListener callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    private boolean hasPermissions() {
        // check for permission
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LOGGER.d("[PERM] onResume");

        if (!hasPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            callback.onPermissionsAcquired();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        // some codes checking

        // if all permissions are okay
        callback.onPermissionsAcquired();
    }

    // callback when permissions successfully acquired
    public interface PermissionsAcquiredListener {
        void onPermissionsAcquired();
    }
}
```

**[Edit]**

Currently I added delay before checking permission. This is just a temporary solution though.

```
    private Runnable task = () -> requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!hasPermissions()) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(task, 500);

        } else {
            callback.onPermissionsAcquired();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried ```android:screenOrientation="landscape"``` inside ```<activity>``` tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Nomankhanbhai 
Yes, inside AndroidManifest.xml is with android:screenOrientation="landscape". The app is only in landscape.

Comment: can you try this ```android:screenOrientation="landscape | locked"``` and let me know if it worked for you @mFad

Comment: I tried and have compile* error AAPT: error: 'landscape | locked' is incompatible with attribute screenOrientation... @Nomankhanbhai

Comment: i think screenOrientation only supports one value remove "locked". let see if something i got. i will let you know @mFad